# AppStore Connect Binary rejected 2. 1 Performance: App Completeness

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, app-store-connect

> We still discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad
>   running iOS 13.3.1 on Wi-Fi.
>
> Specifically, we were unable to login. A wheel is spinning
>   indefinitely. But a call ticket is still ongoing
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device to identify any
>   issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.
>
> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to
>   this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these
>   features were intended to work.
>
> For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a
>   device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For
>   updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version,
>   then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.
>
> Resources
>
> For information about testing your app and preparing it for review,
>   please see Technical Note TN2431: App Testing Guide.
>
> For a networking overview, please review About Networking.

They found that the app is not working an activity indicator spins indefinitely. But while I test the application locally and in TestFlight its working good and our previous version of the application is also working fine. Can anyone help me where I am wrong.

Comment: Try on IPV6 network firstly, secondly check your server logs if at their review time server goes down causing login call to stay there in loop.

Comment: thirdly i recently also facing a behaviour from apple app works on my end and they are continuously saying it's crashing on their end you need to send them strong response i am also following them up.

Comment: Muhammad  - I tried using IPV6 its working fine

Comment: then you must respond with some videos showing app working well, otherwise they will prolong it without any reason. One thing try using proxy to check if your server responding query irrespective of location that can be one of the reason.

Comment: @MuhammadAfzal Thanks I will check using proxy.

Comment: You need to know the real reason why your login service is not working. upload another build with a debugging feature I mean show an alert or screen containing the error message. You just need to enable that debugging feature for a specific login credentials that you've provided to Apple for testing. This way you can know what issue exactly they are facing.

Comment: @SahilManchanda Can you please tell how to enable debugging feature for a service?

Comment: You first need to code this feature in your app. show your code related to service

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any update on this?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I tested with dns64/nat64 as the document says but it is working fine.